# Is it possible to let a variable after a then or else?

Tags: ocaml

I want to make a thing like this : 
        `if is_proximity(leo,bob) = true then let list_1 = create_player(list_1) in list_1 else list_1;;`

When I tried this, I have an error : `Warning 10: this expression should have type unit.`

Note that the function create_player(list_1) add an element to the list_1

Comment: Your `let..in` is missing the `in` part, the expression in which the binding is effective.

Comment: What do you want the value of `list_1` to be when the condition is false?

Comment: Updated, sepp2k, same value

Comment: @FrinkLéo What do you mean by "same value"? Same value as what?

Comment: If condition is true I want that list_1 = create_player(list_1) and if condition is false, list_1 doesn't change.

Comment: @FrinkLéo Are you saying that there's already a variable named `list_1`? And you want that variable to change if the condition is true? You can't do that, variables can't change in OCaml. You'd need a ref for that.

Comment: Arf, yep indeed I have list_1 which is a t_player list. When I want to add an player I have a function which is called create_player() which take a t_player list an add an t_player to this same list. What should I do you think ? Can I use ref for lists ?

Comment: You can, but this really does not seem like a case where you should need `ref`s. Instead you should restructure your code, so that mutating an existing variable isn't necessary. So `create_player` should just return the created player and then the code that creates the player list would call `create_player` and put the result in the list.

Comment: Yes okey but how to put the result in the list without redefining the list ?

Comment: Depending on what you're doing, using functions from the `List` module (`init`, `map`, `filter` or maybe `fold_left`/`_right`) or recursion. But to be honest, if you don't know how to create a list in OCaml, you should probably read through a tutorial before you try to create your own programs.

Comment: I currently learn Ocaml in University and the teacher give us a list of some predefined function.. Ok I'm going to show a tutorial thanks you

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for something like

```
let list1 = … in
…
let list2 = if is_proximity(leo,bob) then create_player(list_1) else list_1 in
…;;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
let list_1 =
  if is_proximity leo bob then
    create_player list_1  (* Or, something like (new_player () :: list_1)? *)
  else
    list_1
in ...
```

The warning you saw points out the type of your expression is a list of some type, not the unit type. If you want to use `list_1` after this, you can use `let ... in ...` or global `let`.